# What is required to sudo without a password on ubuntu?

Tags: sudo

I have got the following line in my /etc/sudoers after editing it via visudo and I am unable to sudo without a password. Does anyone have any ideas on why this is not working properly?

myusername ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

Comment: This works for me, although you could shorten it to `myusername ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL`. Did you log out and back in after you made the change?

Comment: This still doesn't work even after I have re-logged in.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I fixed it. The line needs to be added to the END of the file and not just anywhere for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the above method with no success. Luckily, after hours of dedication I will spare anyone else from having this trouble again :)

`%username%` is the global variable for your username(replace it)

Open up a terminal windows and type

```
sudo usermod -a -G root %username%
```

Then type

```
sudo nano /etc/pam.d/su
```

Goto line 19 and remove the `#` before

```
# auth sufficient pam_wheel.so trust
```

Save your file. Problem solved :)

The first command adds your username to the group:root.

The second command allows all members of root to be su.

Comment: This does not answer the question, and represents what is usually a very bad idea.